# What is power of number like (power of 2, power of 10)? and how to calculate power of number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I know my question is very simple to somebody, but I'm still don't understand so far.

And now my questions about this subject is:

```
What is power of number (ex. 2^6, 4^4)? 
What is the steps to calculate power of number?
```

Please I want very very easy explanation to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand the question. I would just say, "multiply". I don't know of any shortcut, except in special cases (powers of 10, etc.)

Comment: The number $2^6$ is $2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2$. The number $10^3$ is $10\times 10\times 10$. The number $\pi^2$ is $\pi\times \pi$.

Comment: @Eric Auld : I mean this [power of 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expression a^b, let us assume that b is a positive integer.  Then the value of the expression is calculated by multiplying a by itself b times.  thus 2^6 means to multiply 2 by itself 6 times: 2*2*2*2*2**2 = 64.  4^4 is calculated as 4*4*4*4 = 256.  If b is not a positive integer, things become more complicated but I don't think you are ready for that.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can take $2^6$ and break it into smaller powers such as $2^3*2^3$.That should make it easier for you.